# StackAuth returning 404?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackauth

- http://stackauth.com/1.0/sites
- http://stackauth.com/1.0/help

Both of these are currently returning `404 Not Found`. What's up with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackAuth's new DNS record is propagating, expect some outages as per [the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/).

We expect all the DNS issues to shake out well before the recommend `/sites` cache time elapses.

Associated accounts on the sites *themselves* will be kind of weird while that record is propagating, so `/users/{id}/associated` wouldn't really be reliable even if you could get to it.

Comment: I hope so... I might have to manually patch StackMobile's cache - since it refreshes in a few minutes.

Comment: I checked out my code and I noticed that I'm using http://stackauth.com/sites without 1.0 (Not affected by the DNS change).. What's the difference?

Comment: @systempuntoout - `/sites` basically snuck in when we froze 1.0.  There are enough people using it that we can't track down (at least, not without alot of log parsing pain) that I didn't want to just tear it out.  The correct way to use the 1.0 API is to hit `/1.0/sites` directly, we make no guarantees about the lifetime of the raw `/sites` route.

Answer (score 4):

It has been more than 12 hours since I checked http://stackauth.com/1.0/sites, it is still returning a 404. Does anyone have an idea when http://stackauth.com/1.0/sites will be available?

Comment: I was just going to ask this myself :P

Comment: Seems to be working for me now

Answer (score 2):

They are [moving](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/datacenter-migration-oct-23/) datacenters; could be related with that.