# Difference between stackauth URLs

Tags: support

On stackauth theres:

- stackauth.com/sites
- stackauth.com/1.0/sites

Which one should be used (bearing that yesterday the one with the API version was unavailable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting Kevin comment [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/1726/stackauth-returning-404/1728#1728):

> **/sites** basically snuck in when we
>   froze 1.0. There are enough people
>   using it that we can't track down (at
>   least, not without alot of log parsing
>   pain) that I didn't want to just tear
>   it out. The correct way to use the 1.0
>   API is to hit **/1.0/sites** directly, we
>   make no guarantees about the lifetime
>   of the raw /sites  route.

I used to call [/sites](http://stackauth.com/1.0/sites) without api version in my app; it is wrong.

Comment: thanks, ironic then that /1.0/sites couldn't be accessed yesterday but /sites could.